# Ghost4j is throwing PDF document is not valid error while converting a pdf to jpg

Tags: java, ghost4j

I have a requirement to convert a pdf file into jpg image. I have written the below code/logic to convert the pdf as per the documentation provided in the below link.
http://www.ghost4j.org/highlevelapisamples.html

**Code:**

```
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.RenderedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import org.ghost4j.document.PDFDocument;
import org.ghost4j.renderer.SimpleRenderer;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // load PDF document
            PDFDocument document = new PDFDocument();
            File baseFile = new File("Test.pdf");
            document.load(baseFile);

            // create renderer
            SimpleRenderer renderer = new SimpleRenderer();

            // set resolution (in DPI)
            renderer.setResolution(300);

            // render
            List<Image> images = renderer.render(document);

            // write images to files to disk as JPEG
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < images.size(); i++) {
                    ImageIO.write((RenderedImage) images.get(i), "jpg",
                            new File((i + 1) + ".jpg"));
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("ERROR1: " + e.getMessage());
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone please help me why I'm getting "PDF document is not valid" error.

Note: The PDF is valid as I'm able to convert the same pdf to jpg using some other implementation however this implementation is not working if the the image in PDF has CMYK colors.